# Access: how to use a checkbox to control whether to display a message in another cell

Tags: ms-access

I have a Access form with multiple columns. One of column is a text column called "LASTNAME", and I would like to add one checkbox column to control whether this "LASTNAME" displayed or not.

For example,

|---------|-----------|

|  Yes/No |  Mark   |

|---------|-----------|

If checkbox is selected or "Yes", then "Mark" will be displayed, otherwise, "Mark" will not be displayed in my report.

What is the proper way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Checkbox is bound to yes/no field? Expression in textbox: = IIf([checkbox], [LastName], Null)

Comment: I think this Checkbox is not bound to any other field.

Comment: Then every record will show the same value.

Comment: You are right, I should make this checkbox bound to yes/no field.

Comment: I have made it work in the form, but now the problem is how to make get such information updated in table, then to query and report.

Comment: I think the question now comes down to how to bound this expression in textbox to the table. in the Form, under design view, the value is =IIf([Script Only List Notes Checkbox],[Script Only List Notes],""), but in the table, it is Script Only List Note, so after you edit the form, the table does not change. How to make the table update the value after changing the form?

Comment: Just figured out, I took the wrong route, it should go from table to form.